# execution not waiting for promise result in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use promises in AWS Lambda and am having some trouble.  I'm using typescript/nodejs; see code below

```
export function handler(event: any, context: any, callback: Function){

    testFunction().then(data => callback(null, "success from promise"));
    callback(null, "success");
}   

export function testFunction(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("data"), 5000);
    });
}
```

When I run the code I'm getting the "success callback" instead of the "success from promise".  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It won't wait as you resolve your function before it finishes to execute the promise. If you remove `callback(null, "success");` you will see the result you expect

Comment: Is it possible to make it wait until the testFunction delay is finished before moving to the next line of code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are actually calling the callback twice: once on the fourth line `"success"` and once after the promise resolves. I think that lambda will essentially ignore the second callback (which is actually first in your code).

You can merely remove the other call:

```
export function handler(event: any, context: any, callback: Function){
    testFunction().then(data => callback(null, "success from promise"));
}
```

Note: the callback is only supported by Node 4.3. It is also optional. You only need to use it if you want to explicitly pass data back to the caller. Otherwise it will be called automatically once the event loop is empty which in this case will happen after the promise resolves.

You can also change the setting of `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` if you want the lambda function to end immediately when `callback` is called instead of waiting for the event loop to finish. Most likely you won't need to do this, though.

Comment: does not work for me...exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    processRequest(event, function(answer){
     console.log('callback is ' + answer);
        callback(null, answer);
    });
}; the callback is called back but the callback(null, answer) does not do anything